# useEffect warning when adding dependencies using spread operator

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-hooks, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

On passing the dependencies from array to the 2nd parameter of `useEffect`, eslint throws the following error

```
// inputs need to go as part of effects dependency
export function useEffectAsync(effect, inputs) { 
     useEffect(() => {
         effect();
     }, [...inputs, effect]);
}
```

`React Hook useEffect has a spread element in its dependency array. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies`

Usage:

```
useEffectAsync(async () => {
        await dispatch(getData());
        // set something once data is available 
     }
 }, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: What does `inputs` contain?

Comment: That's because the linter will check if a loop exists and that everything that is used within the hook triggers an update, if it changes. That is not possible with the spread parameter. You should be immutable and just add the whole array.

Comment: @Chris it contains dependencies if any required to be passed to the `useEffect`

Comment: @Domino987 But how can I add any other dependency apart from the passed ones?

Comment: @AkshayGundewar like what for example?